# Python RegEx: Delete all lines with less than X characters (removing headings in plain text?)

Tags: python

I try to prepare a plain text file for textual analysis.
I am not interested in Headings and tabular data.

Currently I have a plain text file looking like this:

```
Diluted earnings per share (in EUR) 

Jan 1 – Dec 31, 2021 Jan 1 – Dec 31, 2020 

Changes 

14,348.4 

10,354.0 

424.7 

4.1 

468.4
```

and some Body-text, which I want to keep:

```
Over the next pages, read more about Zalando’s 
2021 progress and how key strategic initiatives are 
helping us to follow through on our vision and to 
achieve our goals.
```

I tried using regex pattern:

(?<=\n)\d{1,10}(?=\n) to at least match the numbers, but it does not work.

Comment: For the numbers try `(?<=\n)(\d|[,.]){1,10}(?=\n)`

Comment: Dear Michael Butscher, thank you very much! It works, and I added some other characters with ?, such as percentage points. Could you explain to me, what the | does? Isnt it an or operator, but acting like an and? Further, is it not possible to do the same for any character, i.e. removing the "Headings"?

Comment: `|` is an "or", meaning the matching character is a digit or a character from the character set (in brackets). To match 1 to 10 arbitrary character(s), use `(?<=\n).{1,10}(?=\n)`. The dot means "any character" (maybe with exception of newline, this depends on  settings).